# Python Recursion does not return true or false

Tags: python

I have a question I try to solve which is to remove a list when they are closing brackets right next to each other like "{[]}", you remove [] first then remove {}. If the list is empty, then you return true otherwise you return false. Below is my code. I wrote a recursion that is not returning me True or False, but it is printing whatever the print statement I put in front of it. I am baffled on why, any ideas?

class Solution:

```
def isValid(self, s: str) -> bool: 
    old_string = s
    print(old_string)
    test_str=[]
    for each_item in old_string:
        test_str.append(each_item)
        print(test_str)
    print (len(test_str))

    #recursion program
    def recursion_function(new_str):
        number=0
        time = 0
        did_something = 0
        if len(new_str) ==0:
            print ("yes")

        for each_string in new_str:
                print (each_string)
                if each_string == ")" and new_str[number-1]=="(":
                    new_str.pop()
                    new_str.pop()
                    print (new_str)
                    did_something = did_something+1
                elif each_string == "]" and new_str[number-1]=="[":
                    new_str.pop()
                    new_str.pop()
                    print (new_str)
                    did_something = did_something+1
                elif each_string == "}" and new_str[number+1]=="{":
                    new_str.pop()
                    new_str.pop()
                    print (new_str)
                    did_something = did_something +1
                number=number+1
        print (did_something)
        if did_something == 0 and len(new_str)!=0: 
            print (new_str)
            print ("hello, why did it get here")
            return False
        elif did_something == 0 and len(new_str)==0: 
            print (new_str)
            print ("did you get here?")
            return True
        else:
            print(new_str)
            print ("see you again this time")
            recursion_function(new_str)

    return recursion_function(test_str)
```

Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: you should probably `return recursion_function` on the third to last line in your prompt. As for the correctness of the rest of your program - idk. I find it hard to read.

Comment: you need to check if pop opereation 2 times when string is matched, it should be `new_string=new_string[1:len(new_string)-1]` you should remove matched parenthesis  not the last 2 element from list

Comment: Why use a nested function for this? As an aside, variable and function names should generally follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thanks, that return recursion_function worked for now. I just need to make sure it returns what I needed.

Comment: Sahasrara62, that is correct, I need to rethink the pop statement. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know if you got it to work yet, but I was going to mention that you are modifying `new_str` inside a `for` loop that is iterating over `new_str`.  That will cause some unexpected behavior.  Also, your usage of the `number` index is a very bad bug; it doesn't necessarily hold the index of the character which precedes `each_str`.  Remember - you are removing characters (with `pop()`) from `new_str`.

Comment: Thanks Rusty, I looked at the solution and found a much elegant way of doing it, basically you build a new stack and if it is "{, (, [" then you keep traversing, and if it is "}, ], )" then you look immediately to its left and if they much, you pop the two.